# What is the final parameter for this function good for?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have tried hunting down the answer to this question for some days, but it's really not explained anywhere, and it's hard to make an experiment to determine the answer.

Look at the documentation for this function: 
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20.html#glUniformMatrix4fv%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20float[],%20int%29](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20.html#glUniformMatrix4fv%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20float%5B%5D,%20int%29)
pretty exhaustive, right?

Sarcasm aside, what is offset good for in:
glUniformMatrix4fv (int location, int count, boolean transpose, float[] value, int offset)

I was thinking that if value[] holds for example 4 matrixes, ie a float[4*4*4] array, the offset determines which following 16 floats that will be uploaded to the GPU.

So if value is:

```
{
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 1,
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0
}
```

and i call the function like so:

```
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, false, values, 16);
```

the identity matrix would be uploaded to the GPU on the specified uniform location?

I've browsed really much and tried to find source code to determine if this is the case, but alas.
I'm sorry for asking a question that SHOULD be covered by an API specification, but it's not.

Comment: I haven't verified it but I'm sure your assumption is correct. The API normally takes a float* as an argument. But you don't have pointers like that in Java; the best you can do is an array and an offset.

Comment: In such cases, it may be handy to refer to the matching, official spec on the Khronos website: 
http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GL's `v` functions are somewhat difficult to explain in a language like Java, which does not support pointers. In C, you can use them to pass all of the arguments it needs using an address to a contiguous block of memory. It is a simple way of passing arguments by array.

Because of the flexibility of passing addresses in a language like C, the C language binding requires only one parameter to represent an arbitrary memory location. In order to replicate the ability to chose an arbitrary location in an array to copy data from, `offset` is necessary in Java.

`glBufferData (...)` has a similar construct, it uses a `java.nio.Buffer`'s "current" position to mark the beginning. This is why you have to `flip (...)` buffers if you fill them by calling `put (...)` repeatedly - it moves the current position back to the beginning of the buffer.

*In fact, the other overload of `GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv (...)` (the one that uses `FloatBuffer`) works exactly the same way as `glBufferData (...)`.*

Comment: Upvoted, but not checked as the answer. If you by "In order to replicate the ability to chose an arbitrary location in an array to copy data from, offset is necessary in Java" mean that my assumption is the case then I'll check it for the answer, but right now I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Stupid comment system, wanted to add the following: Is offset behaving in the same way I proposed, or in some other way entirely?

Comment: @Apeforce: The `offset` is a substitute for pointer arithmetic in C. In C, if you have a `GLfloat *`, you can perform addition on it to increment the address 4-bytes at a time (size of GLfloat) - so to start copying using the 5th element in a `GLfloat` array, you can do `addr + 4`. In Java, pointer arithmetic is meaningless, you have to pass the offset in addition to a reference to your float array. In your example, an offset of **16** coupled with a count of **1** will mean that it copies exactly 16 (num elements in **1** 4x4 matrix) elements from your array, beginning at the identity matrix.

Comment: Ok, so yes then? I know that there are memory pointer in C and object references in Java, that's not what the question was about.

Comment: @Apeforce: Yes. I was just trying to explain why in C the language binding can accomplish the same thing with only 1 parameter. I do not know if you are aware that the Java language binding differs from the C one. In Java, you have to pass an array ***and*** an offset; in C and other languages you can just add a value to the address of an array and then pass that as a single parameter.

Comment: @Apeforce: If you look at the official OpenGL API documentation from Khronos, it always follows the [C language bindings](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glUniform.xml). I thought your question was about why Java's version of `glUniformMatrix4fv (...)` did not match the official specification; in particular, why it had an extra parameter `offset` at the end.

Comment: I've programmed OpenGL in both C++ and Java, so I know that some stuff is different and I realize why Java would need to introduce an offset parameter, if it wants to mimic the behaviour you can get with memory pointers. I was not sure if it indeed WAS trying to mimic that behaviour, or do something else entirely (because there is literary no text at all in the api), that was the question.